# Reposition Row Mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

i want to re-position row when responsive to mobile..

for example the website view

```
<div class="main"> 
  <div > 1</div>  
  <div > 2</div>
  <div > 3</div>
  <div > 4</div>
  <div > 5</div>
</div>
```

when in mobile view, the row 3 change position to row 5..

```
<div class="main"> 
      <div > 1</div>  
      <div > 2</div>
      <div > 5</div>
      <div > 4</div>
      <div > 3</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` and `flex-flow: column;` for the mobile. After that hit the class and give them an `order`.

```css
.one { background: red; padding:25px; font-weight: 900; }
.two { background: orange; padding:25px; font-weight: 900;  }
.three { background: yellow; padding:25px; font-weight: 900;  }
.four { background: green; padding:25px; font-weight: 900;  }
.five { background: blue; padding:25px; font-weight: 900;  }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .main { display: flex; flex-flow: column; }
    .one { order: 1 }
    .two { order: 2; }
    .three { order: 5; }
    .four { order: 4;  }
    .five { order: 3; }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"> 
  <div class="one"> 1</div>  
  <div class="two"> 2</div>
  <div class="three"> 3</div>
  <div class="four"> 4</div>
  <div class="five"> 5</div>
</div>
```